# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

I'm developing with python 3.9.6.
I encounter this error...

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)`

Someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a bit more context but try this:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply
what additional information do you need?